# "\" in JSON response

Tags: node.js, express, quick.db

So my app gets data from my database but it send a response with " \ "

Express response

```
[
          {
                    "ID": "account-saassan",
                    "data": "{\"uuid\":\"saassan\",\"username\":\"sasasasasa\"}"
          }
]
```

Console output:

```
[
  {
    ID: 'account-saassan',
    data: '{"uid":"saassan","username":"sasasasasa"}'
  }
]
```

Code:

```
const UserData = new db.table("userdata")

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', ['*']);
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    next();
});
app.get("/list", (request, response) => {
  
   
    let data = UserData.all()
    console.log(data)
    response.type('json');
    response.json(data)
// I've tried with response.send too. And without response.type
})


app.listen(8080)
```

Why does it add "" in the response and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to using JSON.stringify

```
response.json(JSON.stringify(data))
```

Add please add this :

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: Same thing, adds " \ "